# Diagonalize the matrix $A$ or explain why it can't be diagonalized where $\lambda=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

The matrix $A$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 6 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
For a matrix to be diagonalizable it can be rewritten as $$A=PDP^{-1}$$
where $P$'s columns are the eigenvectors of $A$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Finding the eigenvalues like so
$$\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&0 \\ 6 & -1-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=(1-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)-0=0$$
$$\lambda^2-1=0\therefore \lambda=1$$
So $D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, this is where I'm lost because $D$ is just the identity matrix for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the eigenvectors are the exact same, so how would I write $P$?

Comment: when $\lambda^2 = 1$  then $\lambda = \pm 1$

Comment: You should recognize that when you have an upper (or lower) triangular matrix, the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the second solution of $\lambda = - 1$ giving $\lambda^2 = 1$ so now you have the two $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ eigenvalues you needed.

Comment: I got $D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $P=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}$ does that sound about right?

Comment: @EricBrown perform the multiplication, what do you get?